# copying header from a csv file into a new csv file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a script of my own and I don't know how to copy a header from a csv file into another csv file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CSV, comma separated values, is just a simple text file. Commas are used to indicate columns, and end-of-line (LF, CR or both) indicate end of row.

Just open in a text editor and copy/paste to another file. Tabbed text editors such as Kate or Notepad++ make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I wanted to automate this process by including it in my script.

Comment: You should modify your question to explain that you need to do this through a bash script.